# Multiple Drop Down are not Populating after the API Call

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have Multiple Drop down in my application where each of those are getting the values after the API call. But only in one Dropdown it is populating the values and rest of them are not populating the values.

```html
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:5px;">
            <select bootstrapSelect [(ngModel)]="metricDalaValues"  title="Select Volumes">
               <option 
                   *ngFor="let metricDataOption of responseDropDownDataVal" 
                   [value]="metricDataOption.name" 
                   id="metricDataOption.name">
                   {{metricDataOption.name}} 
               </option>
             </select>
           </div>

             <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:5px;">
                <select class="selectpicker" id ="2"  [(ngModel)]="InstanceValues"  title="Select instances">
                  <option 
                   *ngFor="let instanceDataOptions of responseDropDownDataForInstanceVal " 
                   [value]="instanceDataOptions.resId" 
                   id="instanceDataOptions.resId">
                   {{instanceDataOptions.resId}} 
                 </option>
               </select>
             </div>
```

This is my Typescript file where i make a API Call

```js
responseDropDownData: any;
responseDropDownDataVal = [];
responseDropDownDataForInstance: any;
responseDropDownDataForInstanceVal = [];

this.http.get(environment.envUrl + '/cloudWatch/dropDownForMetrics?' + params, { headers })
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.responseDropDownData = data;
        console.log("Drop Down Data");
        this.responseDropDownDataVal = this.responseDropDownData.data;
        console.log(this.responseDropDownDataVal);
        this.bootstrapSelectDirective.refresh();

    });

this.http.get(environment.envUrl + '/cloudWatch/getInstance?' + params, { headers })
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.responseDropDownDataForInstance = data;
        this.responseDropDownDataForInstanceVal = this.responseDropDownDataForInstance.data;
        console.log("Drop Down Data");
        console.log(this.responseDropDownDataForInstanceVal);
        this.bootstrapSelectDirective.refresh();
    });
```

form an API call I am able to bind the values which are populating in the console but the same data it is not displaying on the dropdownlist Can someone guide me where i did the mistake in the code
[this data is not showing in the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz61E.png)

Comment: Are you using the wrong variable here? `*ngFor="let instanceDataOptions of cities"` I don't see that variable being populated in your code when the data comes back.

Comment: i was checking with the solution mean while i pasted the wrong code i have edited it.
Still it is not working.
You can refer the image where the data is populating. @DanielWStrimpel

Comment: Looks like you don't have a `bootstrapSelect` directive on your second select. That might mean that you need to set up another `bootstrapSelectDirective` variable in your component for that too so you can call the `refresh` method on it.

Comment: thank you @DanielWStrimpel it is working now.
Post the comment as answer ill approve it.